# Using an for/in test with a listed list

Tags: python, list, loops, replace

I've been trying to check if a user submitted string contains a certain substring, and replacing them when printing a reply.

```
list_in_list = [["I", "you"], ["We", "Us"], ["Her", "Him"]]
```

And I've been using the following code to test if the values are in reply as a debug:

```
print [row[0] for row in list_in_list] in reply
```

Where reply is the user inputted string

However it returns this error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

---

I am also having trouble figuring out how to retrieve the correct value to replace.  I'm thinking about looping it with

```
reply.replace(list_in_list[0][x], list_in_list[0][x])
```

where x = amount of loops performed, but I'm stumped about how to code it.

Comment: What are you expecting `[row[0] for row in list_in_list] in reply` to do?

Comment: I was expecting it to return a boolean value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test if any of the values are in `reply` you could do something like

```
print any(row[0] in reply for row in list_in_list)
```

To replace all the values in `reply`

```
for row in list_in_list:
    reply = reply.replace(row[0], row[1])
print reply
```

In response to your comment

```
reply = "This is a test I We Her"
#rw = replace_with
rw = {"I":"You", "We":"Us", "Her":"Him"}

reply = " ".join([rw[word] if word in rw else word for word in reply.split()])

print reply
```

Depending on how complex you input is going to be you might consider using regular expressions or look into natural language processing (for handling contractions and the like).

Comment: Good answer, but it keeps replacing 'I's found in in strings and replacing them. Eg. "This is a test" -> "Thyous yous a test".

Answer (score 1):

did you mean something like:

```
print [row[0] for row in list_in_list if row[0] in reply]
```

This will give you the values in the first column, but only if they are `in reply`.  For example:

```
>>> list_in_list = [["I", "you"], ["We", "Us"], ["Her", "Him"]]
>>> reply = "I like cake"
>>> print [row[0] for row in list_in_list if row[0] in reply]
['I']
>>> reply = "We met Her yesterday"
>>> print [row[0] for row in list_in_list if row[0] in reply]
['We', 'Her']
```